# Suddenly I can not import neither *.pdb nor *.xyz files

Tags: modeling, import, error, file-format

So I was importing without any issue, molecules (pdb or xyz format) to blender, but suddenly this error message appears. Any idea?. I am using the most recent version of blender 2.93.1

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Either your pbd file is not formatted properly or such cases are not handled by the exporter. Have you tried an older version of blender? Otherwise open up `/scripts/add-ons/io_mesh_atomic/pdb_import.py`, go to line 442 and replace the line by `dist_n = dist_n / dist_n.length if dist_n.length else 0`

Comment: @brockmann is there a really valid Python code? I’m not sure. It looks like it’s C or some thing.

Comment: The pdb and xyz files were converted from a sdf file using a program. I will try from a different original format

Comment: @TheLabCat if-else shorthand or ternary conditional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator I recommend get familiar with the python console and just test it.

Comment: @brockmann will do :)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. The solution was easier than that. I just re-started the computer, and voilá.

Comment: Doesn't make sense, the issue will come back...